# How to skip days on successive dates when use carbon php

Tags: php, laravel, date, for-loop, php-carbon

How do I pass successive dates if I use a loop to pass dates that are in the array? I created a simple function to solve my problem but I got stuck when I get > 1 date successive.
Code

```
function daySkip($date, $count=0) {
    $holidays = ["2023-06-19"];

    $MyDateCarbon = Carbon::parse($date);

    $MyDateCarbon->addWeekdays($count);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        if (in_array(Carbon::parse($date)->addWeekdays($i)->toDateString(), $holidays)) {
            $MyDateCarbon->addDay();
        }
    }

    return $MyDateCarbon->format("d-m-Y");
}
```

When I use

```
$input = "2023-06-16";
$addday = daySkip($input, 1);

//output 20-06-2023
```

My code worked. But if there is a change in the holidays array, which for example I also input data 20-06-2023 like

```
$holidays = ["2023-06-19", "2023-06-20"];
```

Then my result is still

```
//output 20-06-2023
```

How to fix that? The date I get should be

```
//output 21-06-2023
```

How do I do a proper loop to get the number of holidays that are in the array? Please advise

Comment: Why not just see if `$MyDateCarbon->toDateString()` is in the array?

Comment: check the `timezone` on `app.php` and the clear the cache.

Comment: Add `++$count;` inside your `if` statement.

Comment: You have added a day that was not in the count so it doesn't get checked.

Comment: If the current day or one in the $count is an holiday, your function won't spot it, so I recommend you don't reinvent the wheel and go for solutions that already exist dedicated to Carbon and holidays handling: https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-day

Comment: Hi @KyleK How to use array data inside `$additionalHolidays` ? I tried to use https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-day

Comment: `$additionalHolidays` is an array already:

`$additionalHolidays = ["2023-06-19", "2023-06-20"];

BusinessDay::enable('Carbon\Carbon', $baseList, $additionalHolidays);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably ment to loop over the `$holiday` array, so I changed

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
```

To

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($holidays); $i++) {
```

So the code is now

```
function daySkip($date, $count=0) {
    $holidays = ["2023-06-19", "2023-06-20"];

    $MyDateCarbon = Carbon::parse($date);

    $MyDateCarbon->addWeekdays($count);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($holidays); $i++) {
        if (in_array(Carbon::parse($date)->addWeekdays($i)->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
            $MyDateCarbon->addDay();
        }
    }
    // return the carbon Object, then format when received from the function call
    // that way you dont have to have the same format all the time you use this func
    return $MyDateCarbon;
}
$input = "2023-06-16";
$addday = daySkip($input, 1);

echo "started with $input and got " . $addday->format("d-m-Y");
```

and the result is

```
started with 2023-06-16 and got 21-06-2023
```

Comment: Hi riggs, when I use another date is fail....I got fail when I try with real data. Maybe you can try $holidays = ["2023-01-01","2023-01-22","2023-01-23","2023-02-18","2023-03-22","2023-03-23","2023-04-07","2023-04-19","2023-04-20","2023-04-21","2023-04-24","2023-04-25","2023-05-01","2023-05-18","2023-06-01","2023-06-02","2023-06-04","2023-06-29","2023-07-19","2023-08-17","2023-09-28","2023-12-25","2023-12-26"];

Comment: The result is `21-06-2023`. The result should be `19-06-2023`

Comment: You said the resuilt should be ... and I quote `//output 21-06-2023`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your for-loop with this. It will add a date every time the new date is in the array

```
while(in_array($MyDateCarbon->toDateString(), $holidays)) {
    $MyDateCarbon->addDay();
}
```